# Amazon reviews: List index out of range

Tags: scrapy

I would like to scrape the customer reviews of the [kindle paperwhite](https://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Paperwhite-Waterproof-Storage-Special/product-reviews/B07CXG6C9W/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_rvwer?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1) of amazon.

I am aware that although amazon might say the have 5900 reviews, it is only possible to access 5000 of them. (after page=500 no more reviews are displayed with 10 reviews per page).

For the first few pages my spider returns 10 reviews per page, but later this shrinks to just one or two. This results in only about 1300 reviews. 
There seems to be a problem with adding the data of the variable "helpul" and "verified". Both throw the following error:

```
'helpful': ''.join(helpful[count]),
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried implementing if statements in case the variables were empty or contained a list, but it didnt work.

My Spider amazon_reviews.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.extensions.throttle import AutoThrottle

class AmazonReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'amazon_reviews'

    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']

    myBaseUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Paperwhite-Waterproof-Storage-Special/product-reviews/B07CXG6C9W/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber="
    start_urls=[]

    # Creating list of urls to be scraped by appending page number a the end of base url
    for i in range(1,550):
        start_urls.append(myBaseUrl+str(i))

    def parse(self, response):
            data = response.css('#cm_cr-review_list')         

            # Collecting various data
            star_rating = data.css('.review-rating')
            title = data.css('.review-title')
            text = data.css('.review-text')
            date = data.css('.review-date'))
            # Number how many people thought the review was helpful.
            helpful = response.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="helpful-vote-statement"]//text()').extract()
            verified = response.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="avp-badge"]//text()').extract()
            # I scrape more information, but deleted it here not to make the code too big

            # yielding the scraped results
            for review in star_rating:
                yield{'ASIN': 'B07CXG6C9W',
                      #'ID': ''.join(id.xpath('.//text()').extract()),
                      'stars': ''.join(review.xpath('.//text()').extract_first()),
                      'title': ''.join(title[count].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()),
                      'text': ''.join(text[count].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()),
                      'date': ''.join(date[count].xpath(".//text()").extract_first()),

                  ### There seems to be a problem with adding these two, as I get 5000 reviews back if I delete them. ###
                      'verified purchase': ''.join(verified[count]),
                      'helpful': ''.join(helpful[count])

                      }
                count=count+1
```

My settings.py :

```
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 2
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 180
REDIRECT_ENABLED = False
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY =5.0
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = True
```

The extracting of the data works fine. The reviews I do get have complete and accurate information. Just the amount of reviews I get are too little.

When I run the spider with the following command:

```
runspider amazon_reviews_scraping_test\amazon_reviews_scraping_test\spiders\amazon_reviews.py -o reviews.csv
```

The ouput on the console looks like the following:

```
2019-04-22 11:54:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Paperwhite-Waterproof-Storage-Special/product-reviews/B07CXG6C9W/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=164> (referer: None)
2019-04-22 11:54:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Paperwhite-Waterproof-Storage-Special/product-reviews/B07CXG6C9W/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=161>
{'ASIN': 'B07CXG6C9W', 'stars': '5.0 out of 5 stars', 'username': 'BRANDI', 'title': 'Bookworms rejoice!', 'text': "The (...) 5 STARS! ", 'date': 'December 7, 2018'}
2019-04-22 11:54:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Paperwhite-Waterproof-Storage-Special/product-reviews/B07CXG6C9W/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=161>
{'ASIN': 'B07CXG6C9W', 'stars': '5.0 out of 5 stars', 'username': 'Doug Stender', 'title': 'As good as adverised', 'text': 'I read (...) mazon...', 'date': 'January 8, 2019'}
2019-04-22 11:54:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.amazon.com/Kindle-Paperwhite-Waterproof-Storage-Special/product-reviews/B07CXG6C9W/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=161> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\John\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\John\OneDrive\Dokumente\Uni\05_SS 19\Masterarbeit\Code\Scrapy\amazon_reviews_scraping_test\amazon_reviews_scraping_test\spiders\amazon_reviews.py", line 78, in parse
    'helpful': ''.join(helpful[count]),
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if a review didnt't have the "verified" tag or if no one commented it, the html part scrapy was looking for isn't there and therefore no item gets added to the list which makes the "verified" and "comments" list shorter than the other ones. Because of this error all items in the list got dropped and werent added to my csv file. The simple fix below which checks if the lists are as long as the other lists worked just fine :)

**Edit:**
When using this fix it might happen that values are assigned to the wrong review, because it is always added to the end of the list.
If you want to be on the safe side, don't scrape the verified tag or replace the whole list with "Na" or something else that indicates that the value is unclear.

```
helpful = response.xpath('.//span[@data-hook="helpful-vote-statement"]//text()').extract()
while len(helpful) != len(date):
                helpful.append("0 people found this helpful")
```